# How do you specify the available values parameters in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

In SSRS ,I'm trying to build a report using this Parameter screen. One of the parameters takes 5 values, shown below:

[image]

[Src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sny9s.png)

However, it's not working.. and I'm not sure why.   I also don't understand what's the difference between "Available values" and "default values" ? Any tips appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Available values are those values that you allow that parameter to have. They are selectable from a drop down list. You can either specify them manually, as you have done, or populate the available values from a dataset.

Default Values holds the initial value that the parameter will be set to. This will be one of the available values. In your example you might set the default value to 0 to indicate a default of "No repsonse to survey". If all the parameters have default values then the report will run automatically.

Now you say it is not working but you don't define what not working means. Please edit your question to define what is happening and what you actually want to happen.

I'll take a quick guess that the values returned aren't being filtered by your parameter selection? If so, you have to use your parameter in the query or the Filter expression of your dataset.

For example, if your parameter is called `Response` then the dataset query should be something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Responses
WHERE ResponseValue = @Response
```

Comment: Thanks very much Chris - I will followup as per your request, I just need a bit of time. Thanks very much

Comment: can I use share dataset as available values for parameters ?